# Python Selenium get list of all links with the same text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using python selenium, how to find all the  links with the same text in a list?

I can use the following code to find a link that has the text '...'

```
button =  driver.find_element_by_link_text('...')
```

But I have more than one of these on the page and would like to click the second one.

Comment: `find_elements_by_link_text`

Comment: Thanks that worked.  If you post as answer I will accept as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find_element_by_` returns the first `WebElement` matching the search criteria. To get all the matching `WebElement`s use `find_elements_by_`

```
driver.find_elements_by_link_text('...')
```

Comment: Great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can you use `find_elements_by_link_text` :

```
driver.find_elements_by_link_text('...')[1].click()
```